# Is there any rule of thumb, to decide whether to override UIView's draw function, or using CAShapeLayer when implementing subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Currently, I have the following custom view

[image]

For the color wheel (component at right) and brightness bar (component at left), I am implementing, by overriding `UIView`'s `draw` function.

For the moveable black/white tiny circle, I am implementing using `CAShapeLayer`.

I was wondering, is there any good rule of thumb, to decide between whether to override `UIView`'s `draw` function, or using `CAShapeLayer` when implementing subview?

Currently, my personal rule of thumb is

1. When the drawing is static, I will implement it by overriding UIView's draw function
2. When the drawing is moveable/ dynamic, I will implement using CAShapeLayer. Reason is that, whenever I move the object, I can just perform `addSublayer`, and need not to call `setNeedsDisplay`, which (maybe) might help in performance?

May I know is there any rule of thumb, to decide whether to override UIView's draw function, or using CAShapeLayer when implementing subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any difference to the render tree whether you use a view or a layer. A view *is* a layer as far as screen rendering is concerned. A view is "merely" a layer plus touchability. A layer can be drawn into using a graphics context just like a view; that in fact is what view drawing does (the view is merely the layer's delegate).

The reasons for using a shape layer are that it is convenient (it just expresses a bezier path) and its properties are animatable.

The reasons for using a view are to get touchability and to get autolayout.

You can combine those two things by making a view whose underlying layer *is* a shape layer.